# What data should I keep in aggregates

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am learning CQRS and event sourcing architecture ([with nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs)), and I am a bit confused by aggregates.

I am following the kind of architecture explained here : https://danielwhittaker.me/2020/02/20/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/

If I understand well, the aggregate root is my "Write Model". It update itself using events which will be committed to the event bus, and I get its current state using event history (or cache).

As I never really read the data in the aggregate root (only the data needed to accept or not the next commands), and I don't persist it (the events are), should I really need to keep all my data in aggregates?

I am not sure if I am clear, so let's see a simplified example :

I've got a `CreateProduct` command for my shopping website, and a `ProductCreated` event. I use the content of the event to create views for some query like `GetProductByCategory`, `SearchProduct`, ...

Here the command :

```
class CreateProduct {
  public name: string;
  public description?: string;
  // ...
}
```

I skip the commandHandler. If I understand well, my aggregate root should be like :

```
class ProductAggregateRoot extends AggregateRoot {
   public id: string;
   private name: string;
   private description?: string;
   
   create(data: { name: string, description?: string }) {
     if (! data.name) {
        throw Error('Name is required');
     }
     this.apply(new ProductCreated(uuid(), data));
   }
   
   onProductCreated(event: ProductCreated) {
     this.id = event.id;
     this.name = event.name;
     this.description = event.description;
   }
}
```

Can I just do :

```
class ProductAggregateRoot extends AggregateRoot {
   public id: string
   
   create(data: { name: string, description?: string }) {
     if (! data.name) {
        throw Error('Name is required');
     }
     this.apply(new ProductCreated(uuid(), data));
   }
   
   onProductCreated(event: ProductCreated) {
     this.id = event.id;
   }
}
```

as I never use `name` and `description` on the command side? It is just usefull for me to create the views on the query side.

It confuses me because it seems to be far from the domain (a Product is more than just an id). But I don't get the point to keep these data here. If I change my mind, I can add it later and rebuild my aggregate roots from the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about nestjs in particular, but in a general implementation of an Event Sourcing application is absolutely OK to only us the fields you need in order to satisfy your business rules. So in this case, since there are no rules involving name or description they don't need to be materialized into the aggregate root class when you handle additional commands (maybe DeleteProduct or similar).

When you apply your next command your application should materialize the aggregate root again from the history of events, so *yes* you can add fields later if needed.

You can see an example from the Serialized Java client here (https://serialized.io/java/working-with-aggregates/) where `OrderPlaced` event contains an `amount` that is not read into the transient state of the Order aggregate when handling commands.